# Como imprimir a quantidade de palavras em uma string que recebe uma frase no .NET?

Tags: c#

Gostaria de imprimir a quantidade de palavras em uma frase declarada dentro de uma *string*.

Exemplo:

```
string frase = "Meu carro vermelho é caro"
cont = 0;
aux = -1;

while(frase.lenght() < frase =="") {
    aux++;
    if(cont < aux){
      cont++;
    }
    Console.writeln(cont);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Utilize [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) e [Length do Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx):

[Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) divide uma string em partes conforme a especificação ou especificações em seu método.

[Length do Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx) traz a quantidade de itens contidos em um array.

```
string frase = "Meu carro vermelho é caro";
string[] palavras = frase.Split(new char[] {' '});
Console.WriteLine(palavras.Length);
```

[Exemplo](http://ideone.com/fork/fJug1V)

**Referencias:**

[Método String.Split (String[], StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Array.Length Propriedade](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: +1 por colocar as referências dos métodos utilizados

Answer (score 4):

`Split` e um método de *strings* que transforma a *string* original em um *array*, utilizando um caracter como parâmetro de 'corte'.

Assim, você só precisa saber o tamanho total do *array* resultante - este será o total de palavras.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string frase = "Meu carro vermelho é caro"; 
        string[] palavras = frase.Split(' '); 
        int totalPalavras = palavras.Length;

        Console.WriteLine(totalPalavras);
    }
}
```

Comment: Só corrija os erros de sintaxe, perfeito.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Maldita mistura de sintaxe JavaScript e C#. ;) Obrigado por apontar o erro.

Comment: Sem problemas @OnoSendai, eu também logo logo erro por saber duas linguagens e acabo confundido tudo ... normal ... só foi mesmo um alerta!

Answer (score -1):

Segue um exemplo simples de fácil implementação:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class StringClassTest
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string characters = "abc\u0000def";
      Console.WriteLine(characters.Length);    // Displays 7
   }
}
```

Fonte: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.length(v=vs.110).aspx